# VueJS Vuex Axios cURL API for Wordpress

Tags: api, vue.js, curl, vuex, axis

I'm using Vuex to make all my API calls and since the beginning the doc was giving example of HTTP requests for displaying posts. But when it comes to CRUD the examples mention cURL requests instead of HTTP ones. It's the first time I'm working with API and I don't know if the syntax/the way I called the API since now is reusable for cURL API. Here's my code so far.

```
state: {
    posts: [],
    cats: [],
  },
  actions: {
    async fetch({ commit }) {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        );
        const data2 = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"
        );
        commit("SET_posts", data.data);
        commit("SET_cats", data2.data);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_posts(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts;
    },
    SET_cats(state, cats) {
      state.cats = cats;
    },
  },
```

And the API call example that deletes a post

```
curl -X DELETE https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id>
```

I guess I have to create another function with at least one argument/parameter since we have to pass the id to make the api call work.

It's the first time I'm using Vuex and the first time I'm using API, sorry if what I'm asking for is obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Add a new action:

```
actions: {
  async fetch({ commit }) {
    ...
  },
  async deletePost({ dispatch }, postId) {
    await axios.delete(
      `http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${postId}`
    );
    // fetching posts again after delete is completed
    await dispatch('fetch');
  },
}
```